# combinator SSS(SS)SS is not strongly normalizing. Why?

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-algebra

I highly speculate that combinator SSS(SS)SS is not strongly normalizing.  What is the argument for the non strong normalization?

Comment: Could you give some motivation for this? Why do you suspect it is not strongly normalizing? Also, why is this particular combinator interesting?

Comment: I suspect it is strongly normalizing because it reduces as follows (no room for that)

This combinator is interesting because it is the smallest with is no SN. 

Answer (score 5):

Did you have a look at the second part of Johannes Waldmann's thesis [The Combinator S](http://www.imn.htwk-leipzig.de/~waldmann/pub/phdthesis/) ?

He proves that the normalization of S-based combinators is decidable and provides a procedure. SSS(SS)SS does not normalize.

He also refers to Dobouè's combinator S(SS)SSSS which does not normalize.

Comment: These are the same thing. $S(SS)SSSS \to SSS(SS)SS$ after its first S-combinator evaluation.